# Addition of an Extra link to an existing link

Tags: network-share

I would like to know how to configure a extra link to my Mikrotik Routern or Cisco 3800 series router.In my office our bandwidth is 1mb, which is insufficient.But an extra 4mb was made available to us by a different ISP/hub.How do we integrate this new link into our existing link to boost our bandwidth (N.B it uses a private IP)?Our router has 2 interfaces:1 to the modem n the other to the switch.Kindly reply asap.

Comment: Are you asking about using a dual WAN router or trying to use two connections as one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but what you want it's known as link aggregation. I can't help without further info